# Angular group request mongodb

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I have a `$group` request in my backend

```
const buildingsPerCampus = data.collection('buildings').aggregate(
  [{
    $group: {
      _id: "$idCampus",
      buildingName: {
        $push: "$buildingName"
      }
    }
  }]);
```

What can I do in angular (my frontend) to call it?

I just modified my request to sort my buildings by `campusName`

```
db.getCollection('buildings').aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: "$campusName",
    buildingName: {
      $push: {
        buildingName: "$buildingName",
        phoneNumber: "$phoneNumber"
      }
    }
  }
}]);
```

but I don't know the syntax in my angular service to get this array to put it in a table.

That's my http request on my frontend to get the building and what I need is to sort them.

```
getBuildings() {
  return this.http.get(`${this.url}/buildings`);
}
```

I did it like this but I dont know if it's correct:

```
app.get('/buildings', (req, res) => {
    db.db('').getCollection('buildings').aggregate([
        {$group : {_id: "$campusName", buildingName : {$push : {buildingName : "$buildingName", phoneNumber :"$phoneNumber" }}}}
      ]).toArray(function (err, building) {
        if (err) {
            res.send({ 'error': 'en error has occured'});
        } else {
            res.send(building);
        }
    });
});
```

Here'is my get `buildings` working with angular, what I want is sorting by `campuses`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nchz.png

and my aggregate request in robo3T

https://i.stack.imgur.com/75IsM.png

what do you think about this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Vaoq.png

Finally, I did it. I just changed my get request with the new one, now I just need to put this in my angular front, have any idea? I need a selector or a table I don't know.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hP2T.png

Comment: expose it as a REST API and then use `HttpClient`'s method to get the data.

Comment: just edited my post :)

Comment: Are you able to get the JSON data directly by hitting that API in Postman or a browser(only in case of GET)?

Comment: yes i can get the json for basic requests but what i want is getting the result of the aggregate one

Comment: Exactly my point. Are you getting the data for the aggregation one that you might have exposed as a REST API? Have you exposed this aggregation operation as a REST API in the first place?

Comment: i edited my post

Comment: Yeah, but is hitting "localhost:PORT/buildings" in the browser returning any data?

PORT is the port you're listening for incoming requests on.

Comment: i sent the screen with my vue and the aggregation request in robo3T

Comment: I think you didn't understand my point. I'm asking you to share a screenshot of you hitting the request from the browser. Since it is a GET request, you should receive a JSON response from the API. I want to see that JSON response and the request URL that you're using to get the data.

Comment: hi i just edited the post i changed my get request and it works now i want to put all in my angular front, maybe a selector campuses with a building array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you've exposed your API here: https://www.your-domain.com/buildings. You can get the response by calling HttpClient's get method on it.

So you'll first create an Angular Service that has HttpClient injected as a dependency.

Then you'll create a method that you've already done here:

```
getBuildings() {
  return this.http.get(`${this.url}/buildings`);
}
```

And finally, you'll be able to get the data from this method.

The `get` method returns an Obsrvable that you need to `subscribe` to, to unwrap the data.

So in your component's TypeScript class, generally in the `ngOnInit()` method, call you service's `getBuildings()` method and subscribe to it to get the actual data.

Here's what it looks like in code: [StackBlitz Project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vhjmdg)